# Entity framework apply format on getting value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a property that is mapped by EF to database column

```
public string ImageName { get; set; }
```

For instance this property may return `0.jpg` but the full path on my server is `urlOfPallication/Folder/0.jpg` I would like to make getter return this path, how can I apply formatting upon getting this value?

Comment: Save the path in the database, use the path functions to get the filename/directory/ ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new readonly property that return an Uri instance like below:

```
public Uri ImageUri
{
    get
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ImageName) ? null : new Uri(string.Format("urlOfPallication/Folder/{0}", this.ImageName));
    }
}
```

Use that property if you want to get the URI (`Uri.ToString()`) if you want to get the URL of the image. Just because it is a readonly property you don't need to decorate it with `NotMapped` attribute because EF don't care about readonly property.

You final should have both `ImageName` and `ImageUri` properties. The first one is use for storing the name of the image and the latter for getting the image URL.

Comment: I'm going to do this, do you know how to get url of appliuction?

Comment: If you want it to work in production and all other environements just use a relative URL. don't put the domain. When the relative part of the URL reach the UI application it will know how to solve it if you use Web app. With rich client like WPF, WinForm you should concactenate with the domain alwyas in the UI part.

Comment: So `"urlOfPallication/Folder/{0}"` should be `"/Folder/{0}"` :)